# DDB stream Lambda tumbling window retry behaviour

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams, dlq

I am using Lambda with DDB trigger to listen to DDB stream. I am not clear about retry behavior of Lambdas with tumbling window.

If I am maintaining a state of x in 5 minutes of tumbling window with DDB stream batch size of 10, and my nth lambda fails, what information will be passed to DLQ if I set a on failure destination? Is it the batch size from Lambda 1 to Lambda n or just the batch size of Lambda n? and does it also send the state to DLQ in the metadata?

Comment: Is https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-aws-lambda-controls-for-stream-processing-and-asynchronous-invocations/ useful for you?

Comment: It does not cover tumbling window feature. Using tumbling window I can store a state between different lambda invocations. My question is, if in the middle of the window the lambda breaks, then what will be sent to the DLQ.